# System Programing | Scheduling Times

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, round-robin

I'm trying to understand these scheduling algorithms:

- First-Come-First-Served (FCFS)
- Shortest job first (SJF)
- Shortest remaining time (SRT)
- Round-robin (RR)

So, given some input:

```
Process Name: A; Arrival Time: 0; Expected CPU Running Time: 3
Process Name: B; Arrival Time: 1; Expected CPU Running Time: 5
Process Name: C; Arrival Time: 3; Expected CPU Running Time: 2
Process Name: D; Arrival Time: 9; Expected CPU Running Time: 5
Process Name: E; Arrival Time: 12; Expected CPU Running Time: 5
```

FCFS would schedule as `AAABBBBBCCDDDDDEEEEE`.

I can't seem to figure the rest out. Can someone help explain the difference to me?

I tried Googling but the result I got for SJF is kind confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give you some hints.

For SJF and SRT you don't really definitions - just think logically about the name.

For **SJF**, pick the shortest arrived unfinished job. Use the total time of the job, i.e. 3,5,2,5,5 - pay no attention to how much has already been scheduled for that job.

For **SRT**, pick the arrived unfinished job with the least remaining time. The remaining time is simply defined as the total time minus how much has already been scheduled. So, at time 2, you'd have scheduled `AA`, thus the remaining time for `A` would be `3-2 = 1`.

For SJF and SRT, **conflicts** (when there are two jobs with the same times) can probably be resolved by picking the job that arrived first. For SRT, conflicts may also be resolved by picking the longest job. You'll have to confirm this.

Note that there are two variations for these algorithms - **preemptive** and **non-preemptive**. In short, preemptive means that, at every time step you pick the job to execute next. For non-preemtive, on the other hand, once you've picked a job, you schedule that job until it's finished, no matter whether or not there's a newly arrived job with a shorter time. See [this](http://siber.cankaya.edu.tr/OperatingSystems/ceng328/node123.html) for a more detailed explanation.

For **RR**, just pick the one you've picked the longest ago.

Comment: so sjf would be AAACCBBBBBDDDDDEEEEE?

Comment: I still don't get your explanation for SRT.

Comment: @NewFile I modified my explanation a bit.

Comment: ABBCCAABBBDDDDDEEEEE for SRT?

Comment: @NewFile No. Let's look at time 1. RT for A = `3-1 = 2`, RT for B = `5-0 = 5`, and 2 < 5, thus you need to pick A, not B.

Comment: so AAABCCBBBBDDDDEEEEEE? sorry for the stupidity im having such a hard time figuring those out

Comment: @NewFile Replace `BCC` by `CCB`, then yes. At time 3, RT for B = 5, RT for C = 2. Oh, and you have 1 too many E's and 1 too few D's.

Comment: question. how come SJF and SRT result the same?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40438/discussion-between-newfile-and-dukeling)